# Does declaring an array of lambda functions with reference captures cause Heap Allocation?

Tags: c++

Recently, I am told that declaring an array of lambda functions with reference captures cause Heap allocation. I don't see how this could be true. If true, how and is it possible to do refactoring to avoid Heap Allocation?

For visualization purposes:

```
std::function<void(void)> func1 = [a few ref captures here](no argument) -> void { ... }
std::function<void(void)> func2 = [a few different ref captures here](no argument) -> void { ... }
std::function<void(void)> func3 = [a few different ref captures here](no argument) -> void { ... }

std::array<std::function<void(void)>, 3U> func_array{ func1, func2, func3 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dynamic allocation comes from your use of `std::function<void(void)>` which uses dynamic allocation for type erasure.

You would need to refactor the `std::function`s out and that's going to be really hard / potentially impossible to do as your closures have different types.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Answer to the topic is given by @NathanOliver. Below is an alternative to whom this may be interesting.

For anyone who stumbles upon this page, a rather "pretty" alternative that does not do Heap Allocation is using class methods pointers;

```
const static std::array<return_type(Class_name::*)(arguments_of_the_methods), size_of_array> name_of_the_array
{{
    &Class_name::method1,
    &Class_name::method2,
    &Class_name::method3
}};
```

For sure the methods should now be a part of a class. All the methods should have the same argument list and all the variables captured in the capture list of lambdas should be member variables of the class.

Comment: You aren't actually answering the question. This answer is interesting, but it's additional info while the actual answer is missing.